# Which row in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame by multipul logicals

Tags: r, r-sp

I have a single SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in which I have 3 islands. On these islands, there are named locations however the names are not unique between islands. I have found a way to identify which names are replicated between the various island but I can not get back to which row they correspond to. Ideally I would find a way to access those rows so I can modify the location name to create name that's unique between islands.
Using the Meuse data set from sp I came up with this

```
library(sp)
data("meuse")
coordinates(meuse) <- ~ x + y
str(meuse)
a <- meuse[meuse$lime == "0" && meuse$landuse == "Ah",]
dim(a)
subset(meuse, lime == "1")
```

The return of `a` is 0 but when you look at the last subset line there are clearly rows that fit that condition. Any suggestions on what I'm missing here or what I should be doing instead?

Comment: all the data on meuse has sold == "1"

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. `a` has zero rows because no `soil == 0` in the dataset. In contrast, `subset(meuse, soil == "1")` has more than zero rows because there are `soil == 1` in the dataset. Everything works as expected.

Comment: thanks @CarlosSantillan and www there was a problem with my example. When I change soil to lime however, you can see that I am still unable to subset in the ways I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `&&` in

```
a <- meuse[meuse$lime == "0" && meuse$landuse == "Ah",]
```

As the documentation says,

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The
>   shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as
>   arithmetic operators. **The longer form evaluates left to right
>   examining only the first element of each vector.**

For instance,

```
c(TRUE, TRUE) && c(FALSE, TRUE)
# [1] FALSE
c(TRUE, TRUE) & c(FALSE, TRUE)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

So, instead you want

```
a <- meuse[meuse$lime == "0" & meuse$landuse == "Ah",]
dim(a)
# [1] 31 12
```

Comment: @Reed, does it help?